# I cannot instantiate my teststeps in cucumber class step_definitions.LoginSteps doesn't have an empty constructor

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, cucumber-java

I get an error when I run my feature test.Does this have to do with the webdriver constructor in the login page? I can't figure out why I"m getting this error:

cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: class step_definitions.LoginSteps    doesn't have an empty constructor. If you need DI, put cucumber-picocontainer on the classpath...

I have picocontainter in my pom
    info.cukes
            cucumber-picocontainer
            1.2.4

```
public class LoginSteps  {
private final LoginPage login;
SharedDriver driver;
public LoginSteps(LoginPage login, SharedDriver driver) {
    this.login=login;
    this.driver=driver;
}
@Given("^the Pctice Login page is loaded$")
public void the_Poactice_Login_is_loaded ()throws Throwable {
   driver.getDriver().get("....ogin/");
}


@When("^The logins into the account$")
public void the_logins_into_the_account() throws Throwable {

    login.login(false);

  }
```

Here is my login page

```
    public class LoginPage extends BaseClass {
  private final By username = By.id("userName");
   private final By password= By.id("password");
   private final By submit= By.id("submit_0");

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
     super(driver);
    }


   public HomePage login(Boolean newuser) throws InterruptedException {
    DataFactory log= new DataFactory();
    if (newuser) {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(username).click();
        driver.findElement(username).sendKeys(log.getFirstName());
        driver.findElement(password).sendKeys(log.getFirstName());
    } else {
        driver.findElement(username).click();

    }

    return new HomePage(driver);
}}
```

Comment: If the subclass lacks a constructor doesn't java invoke the superclass;s constructor by default?  Do you really need the constructor in the LoginPage subclass?

Comment: The problem seems pretty clear from the message. LoginSteps class does not have a default constructor, therefore cannot be instantiated automatically by Cucumber.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the same version of cucumber for the cucumber-picocontainer. 
Then you must add to **CLASSPATH** (in EnviromentsSetting of Windows), the path to your cucumber-picocontainer-version.jar, located in your .m2 repository, for example:
 `"C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-picocontainer\5.7.0\*"`. Finally, restart the IDE for take the changes.

You can check if your **CLASSPATH** is available in your IDE console, with the command: `set CLASSPATH`

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not put constructors in my step-definition classes.

LandingPageSteps.java

```
package practice.steps;

import practice.pages.LandingPage;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class LandingPageSteps extends DriverFactory{

    @When("^she chooses to sign up$")
    public void she_chooses_to_sign_up() throws Throwable {
        new LandingPage(driver).she_chooses_to_sign_up();
    }
}
```

DriverFactory.java

```
package practice.steps;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import practice.util.PropertyReader;

public class DriverFactory {

    protected static WebDriver driver;

    public DriverFactory() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        if (driver == null)
            createNewDriverInstance();
    }

    private void createNewDriverInstance() {
        PropertyReader propReader = new PropertyReader();
        String browser = propReader.readProperty("browser");
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:/SeleniumWebdrivers/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else {
            System.out.println(propReader.propertyNotValidMsg("browser", browser));
        }
        Assert.assertNotNull("Driver failed initialization", driver);
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void destroyDriver() {
        driver.quit();
        driver = null;
    }
}
```

Note that the superclass does have a constructor.  I was evaluating this free [eBook](https://www.gitbook.com/book/sukesh15/cucumber-jvm-test-framework-/details) by working through it.  Maybe if you work through it yourself you would realize a more coherent approach.  I found it to be pretty solid (I put my hooks in a separate file from the step definitions but it is a matter of taste).
}

Comment: Can we use the same approach for iOS Automation also using Serenity BDD? Is this code available on GitHub to take a pull?